# Chaining two promises using async/await

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, chaining

Suppose I have this function that need to chain two promises

```
async function getPosts() {
  let p1 = await fetch(...)
  let p2 = await fetch(...)
  let post1 = await (await p1).json()
  let post2 = await (await p2).json()
  ...
}
```

Do I need to use a double `await` to get a fulfilled result into `post1` or is it redundant?

```
async function getPosts() {
  let p1 = await fetch(...)
  let p2 = await fetch(...)
  let post1 = await (p1).json()
  let post2 = await (p2).json()
  ...
}
```

Comment: You could just do `let post1 = await fetch(...).then(r => r.json());`.  Unfortunately, `fetch()` was designed to force you into two steps to get the parsed content.  Also, please realize that your variables `p1` and `p2` are not promises because you've already `awaited` the promises `fetch()` returned.  They are the resolved result from `fetch()`so they might be better named `result1` and `result2` or `r1` and `r2`.

Comment: The double await you show in the first code block is not necessary.  `p1` and `p2` in your code are already resolved results because you've already used `await` on the promise that `fetch()` returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to away an expression that returns a promise. `fetch` returns a promise, and so does the `json()` method.

```
async function getPosts() {
  let p1 = await fetch(...)
  // fetch() returns a promise, `await p1` unwraps that promise.

  let post1 = await p1.json()
  // p1 is a fetch response, just await the `json()` method.
}
```

But, you can get a little cleaner by mixing promise callbacks and `await` syntax:

```
let post1 = await fetch(...).then(res => res.json())
```

Here `fetch()` returns a promise with a `then()` method. And `then()` here will return a promise that resolves when JSON content has been parse.